# Enable http actuator with disable default web server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I need create spring boot application as daemon with disabled default web server and with active server actuator by http.

I need actuator only by http no jmx.

Actuator should work by 7001 port and should expose only actuator endpoints without bissnes @RestController endpoints.

My configuration:

`management.server.port: 7001`

Maven dapendecy:
    
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

With above configuration spring boot run with two TomcatWebServer 8080 (default) and 7001 actuator:

`2019-11-22 20:49:50.246  INFO 4824 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 7001 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-22 20:49:50.256  INFO 4824 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`

But i want only actuator 7001.

I can add to properties file `spring.main.web-application-type=none`
but it disable all web servers.

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Hello! Did you find an answer?..

Comment: @Cepr0 Answer no but workaround yes.

Comment: Could you share it please? )

Answer (score 1):

you can also set `server port` to *7001* and `TomcatWebServer` will start once

**application.properties**:

```
server.port=7001
management.server.port=7001
```

*log output*:

```
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 7001 (http)
Tomcat started on port(s): 7001 (http) with context path ''
```

Comment: i know i can but i dont want serve bissunes endpoints, i want serve only actuator endpoints.